# Heroku returns 400 Bad Request Response (Socket.IO Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

A 400 Bad Request is returned every time Socket.IO connects to my Heroku app. How do I fix this?

I have a Node.js web app that uses Socket.IO. There are no problems while in local development but when I deployed the app to Heroku, every socket.io connection returns a 400 Bad Request. I've tried manually setting the transport method to websocket, polling, and both but it still doesn't work. I've also turned on session affinity for my dyno.

In the server I have

```
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);

const namespace = io.of('/client-web-app');
```

the client connects through

```
const socket = io('/client-web-app')
```

as you ordinarily do.

Browser console logs the following:

```
polling-xhr.js:269 POST https://<app-name>.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mo5GHwF&sid=7Pn_tN47tE2NqFKMAAAc 400 (Bad Request)
```

there is also a GET and websocket versions of the request

Meanwhile, Heroku logs the following:

```
 at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mo5GjRq&sid=wSTQhI8NQRpLbb3xAAAm" host=<app-name>.herokuapp.com request_id=da83df98-0522-4e0a-b0cc-fdbc3304b7f8 fwd="110.54.138.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=400 bytes=296 protocol=https
2019-08-12T09:57:28.339289+00:00 app[web.1]: device disconnected
2019-08-12T09:57:28.628468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mo5GjRs&sid=wSTQhI8NQRpLbb3xAAAm" host=<app-name>.herokuapp.com request_id=99ba8299-6f8a-448f-a8ce-d0b34b4a062f fwd="110.54.138.89" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=400 bytes=228 protocol=https
```

replaced my actual application name with `<app-name>` for reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution to my own problem. Posting here in case anyone else is having the same problem as mine. Just explicitly state that you going to use `websocket` as your transport.

So in your socket.io server:

```
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server, {transports: ['websocket']});
```

and in your socket.io client:

`const socket = io('/client-web-app', {transports: ['websocket']});`

It seems Heroku only supports `websocket` as a socket.io transport.

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly! I'll open a PR about this to socketIO docs.

Comment: still not working, i had to move the site off heroku to add nginx header: https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

Comment: Hi, I had added 'websocket' option for both server and client. Still seeing similar error. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is one solution, but maybe not the best — there are cases where the polling transport is still desirable, and it works fine with Heroku as long as session affinity is enabled, as per [the docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes/#enabling-sticky-session).

What's missing is probably the detail in the the '**Important Note**' in that section of the docs (copied below) — if your client and server are on different domains and rely on CORS, then you need to make sure that you configure both the socketio server and client to pass along the credentials (i.e. cookie) in order to make the session affinity work.

From the socket.io docs:

**Important note**: if you are in a CORS situation (the front domain is different from the server domain) and session affinity is achieved with a cookie, you need to allow credentials:

Server

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://front-domain.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

Client

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io("https://server-domain.com", {
  withCredentials: true
});
```

Without it, the cookie will not be sent by the browser and you will experience HTTP 400 "Session ID unknown" responses.